# Ubuntu 20.04: JBL Jump microphone not detected

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, microphone

I recently bought the JBL Endurance Jump bluetooth earphone+mic. The audio is working without glitches and the bluetooth pairing works fine, but the microphone is not getting detected by the OS.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: Does anyone know how to bump this up? Not really getting a lot of responses on this. I don't know if I should repost this somewhere else to get more eyeballs on this thing.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It only works when I use the wired option. My model is JBL LIVE650BTNC.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, I am using Oneplus Bullets Wireless Z on Ubuntu 20.04. The mic was detected and working fine a few days also, but after recent OS updates seems to have broken things.

Comment: Same problem :(

Comment: @Anshik You can see my answer below and check if it fixes your problem

Comment: @rainu I was also facing the issue on Oneplus Wireless Z and ubuntu 20.04, you can check my answer below to fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue with Oneplus Wireless Z Bass edition. My headset microphone was not detected by PulseAudio and the problem is that my headphones  don't have HSP profile, only HFP profile. After trying for 2 days, I came to the solution of replacing PulseAudio with Pipewire sound server, which supports HSP, HFP and A2DP by itself. So there will be no need to install any other utility like `ofono`, `phonesim`. Also, to be noted that my problem wasn't resolved even after following all the steps to configure `ofono` in PulseAudio. So I came up with the steps to replace PulseAudio with PipeWire.

Here is the detailed article I have written to resolve this problem, the steps of which I'm also adding here. You can follow it and most probably be able to solve your problem.

[Bluetooth headset microphone not detected](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0)

Open your terminal and follow these steps:

1. We will use a PPA for adding Pipewire to Ubuntu 20.04, which is maintained regularly:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
   ```
2. To update the PPA packages in your system do:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire
   ```
4. There is also a dependency needed to be installed with Pipewire, otherwise you will face the issue of *“Bluetooth headset won’t connect after installing pipewire”*. Install the dependency by:

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```
5. Now, to install the client libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
   ```
6. Reload the daemon:

   ```
   systemctl --user daemon-reload
   ```
7. Disable PulseAudio:

   ```
   systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
   ```
8. If you are on Ubuntu 20.04, you also need to “mask” the PulseAudio by:

   ```
   systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
   ```

I am not sure but, if possible, you can try to run this on other versions too.
9.     After a new update of Pipewire, you also need to enable `pipewire-media-session-service`:

```
   systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service
```

10. You can ensure that Pipewire is now running through:

    ```
    pactl info
    ```

    This command will give the following output, in Server Name you can see:

    ```
    PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.28)
    ```

    Things should be working by now and you can see your microphone.

If it doesn’t show up, then try restarting Pipewire by this command:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire
```

If it’s still not showing your microphone, you can try rebooting once and remove and pair your Bluetooth device again to check if it works now.

I hope I have helped you solve your problem.

If you want to rollback all the changes we did, you can do it by using:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

Comment: this solution worked for me OOB (after computer restart) after trying other fixes such as adding `load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=2` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` succeeded to get the headphone working but mic still failing

Comment: note also that I have JBL Aero with a case. If i put my headphones into the case, they disconnect from the computer. When I remove the headphones from the case and use them, they will connect automatically, but not be added to the sound settings. If I open the bluetooth settings, disconnect the headphones, then reconnect, everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to switch A2DP Sink to HSP/HFP

My JBL mic works if I do this. So I switch back to A2DP Sink if I will listen to music.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. A2DP or HSP doesn't detect the mic. I do have a Logitech webcam with internal mic and that seems to work with both modes. But for JBL Jump I can't enable the mic on either of those modes.

The earphones work flawlessly on my other devices, like phone/laptop. Both the earpiece and mic are working, so I guess this problem is Ubuntu specific.